# Some users can't login with Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a strange issue regarding my website. The problem is that I have implemented a Facebook login which seems to be working correctly. BUT it happens that for some users it simply does not work. It does not give any error message, simply redirects to the same page where the Facebook-login button was clicked. So my user clicks the login button on my page and no pop-up no error message, just gets back to the login page.

It has happened only once that my client has received the following error message: "Ex code: 100 Ex msg: This authorization code has been used."

I don't know what could cause the problem as it is quite strange for me that basically it works for some people and not for others...

I don't really know what other information should I post but if someone requests more info I can provide them. I'm using Facebook JS SDK with PHP SDK.

update 1:
relevant part in login.php:

```
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {    
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      $('#fb-login-auth').show();
      $('#fb-login-not-auth').remove();
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      // document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log into Facebook.';
      $('#fb-login-not-auth').remove();
      $('#fb-login-auth').show();
    }
  }
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: <?php echo FB_APP_ID; ?>,
      cookie : true,// enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml: true,// parse social plugins on this page
      version: 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      //TODO replace absolute link withr elative one for FB
      window.location = '/projects/salty/main/users/fblogin';
    });
  };
  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/hu_HU/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      $('#fb-login-auth').remove();
      $('#fb-login-not-auth').show();
      $('.fb_iframe_widget').remove();
    });
  }
</script>
...
echo $this->Html->link('<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Login with FB',
                       array('action' => 'fblogin'),
                       array('id' => 'fb-login-not-auth',
                             'escape' => false));
```

fblogin.php:

```
<h1 class="center">Facebook login</h1>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('._4z_f').click();
    });
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: <?php echo FB_APP_ID; ?>,
    cookie : true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.2'
  });

  FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.status === "connected") {
      var uID = response.authResponse.userID;
      console.log(uID);
      FB.api('/me', function (response) {});
    } else if (response.status === "not_authorized") {
      //authCancelled. redirect
    }
  },
  {
    scope: 'user_location,user_likes'
  });
};//closes window.fbAsynInit
// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/hu_HU/all.js";
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script> 
<h1 id="redirecting">Redirecting</h1>
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

The relevant controller action for fblogin:

```
  public function fblogin() {
    if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
      return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    }
    \Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(FB_APP_ID, FB_APP_SECRET);
    $fbHelper = new \Facebook\FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();
    try {
      $session = $fbHelper->getSession();
    } catch(Facebook\FacebookRequestException $ex) {
      echo "Ex code: " . $ex->getCode();
      echo "Ex msg:  " . $ex->getMessage();
      return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
      // When Facebook returns an error
    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
      echo "Ex code: " . $ex->getCode();
      echo "Ex msg:  " . $ex->getMessage();
      return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
      // When validation fails or other local issues
    }
    if ($session) {
      $access_token = $session->getToken();
      $appsecret_proof = hash_hmac('sha256', $access_token, FB_APP_SECRET);
      $request = new \Facebook\FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,email', array("appsecret_proof" =>  $appsecret_proof));
      $response = $request->execute();
      $user = $response->getGraphObject(\Facebook\GraphUser::className());
      $checkPermissions = new \Facebook\FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/permissions', array("appsecret_proof" => $appsecret_proof));
      $checkResponse = $checkPermissions->execute();
      $permissionsObject = $checkResponse->getGraphObject(\Facebook\GraphUser::className());
      $permissions = json_decode(json_encode($permissionsObject->asArray()), true);
      $isEmailPermissionGiven = true; 
      foreach($permissions as $permission) {
        if ($permission['permission'] == 'email'
            && $permission['status'] == 'declined') {
          $isEmailPermissionGiven = false;
        }
      }
      $fbUser = array();
      $fbUser['User']['username'] = $user->getName();
      $fbUser['User']['last_name'] = $user->getFirstName()." ".$user->getMiddleName();
      ...
      $this->Auth->login($user['User']);
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance,
Zoltan

Comment: Did the users for which the fb login is not working have registered facebook with email or phone number, and have they made their email id private in facebook

Comment: You should show some code.

Comment: They have registered with e-mail and their email is not visible for public.

Comment: Do they have a popup blocker? Do they disabled their cookies?

Comment: no they didn't have. I have tried to login with my own FB account and with my customer's FB account on the same machine - it worked for me but not for the customer.

Comment: I have added some source code.

Comment: From the message your client got, it sounds like somehow he's trying to log in to Facebook twice. Is your page redirecting many times without you knowing so? I would check this first.

Comment: Ye, I have noticed that there is one more redirection than needed (sometimes when I go to the login page where the FB login button is placed, it automatically refreshes the page and logs me in). Can it be the cause? Why isn't it a problem for other users?